# Ensure fields with same type across documents in a collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I am in the process of migrating a database in MySQL to MongoDB. However, I am running into a problem where MongoDB changes the document type based on the length/value of the string/integer data used to initialize it. Is there a way to prevent this? I want the types to be same across a collection.

I am new to this technology and apologize if I missed something. I looked around and could not find a solution to this. Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

thanks,

Asha

Comment: it would help if you let us know how you are migrating this data.

Comment: Oh, I just intend to duplicate the data for now. All the collections will have the same structure as their MySQL counterparts. So essentially, I am writing some java and C++ programs to copy over the data.

Comment: What is a "document" type in MongoDB? Do you mean "element" types, i.e. fields of the document? (as described in the docs here: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Data+Types+and+Conventions) If that is the case, then using the driver you should be able to define field type in the queries... like @Asha suggested, share some code that does the copying and we may try to debug :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're writing your migration application in C++, check out the BSONObjBuilder class in "bson/bsonobjbuilder.h".  If you create your individual BSON documents using the "append" methods of BSONObjBuilder, the builder will use the static types of the fields to set the appropriate BSON type in the output object.

For example:

```
int count = /*something from a mysql query*/;
std::string name = /*something else from a mysql query*/;
BSONObjBuilder builder;
builder.append("count", count);
builder.append("name", name);
BSONObj result = builder.obj();
```